# Pass @selector an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview, selector

I have an animation block on a UIView, and would like to pass my `animationDidStopSelector` an object, so that when my animation finishes, the object can be removed from an array.

The following code, doesn't work.

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStopWithObject:)];
    self.dialogController.view.alpha=1;
[UIView commitAnimations];

    [self.view addSubview:self.dialogController.view];
}

- (void)animationDidStopWithObject:(NSString*)obj {
    [items removeObject:obj];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

How can i pass my selector an object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check UIView reference. Selector you pass to +setAnimationDisStopSelector: method must be of the form

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
```

You can pass your object to that selector using animations context (void* pointer passed as parameter in +beginAnimations:context: call)

Comment: Thanks... I would like to use the blocks API (much simpler), but cannot for legacy users.

Comment: Yes, I had to support 3.x users as well and sadly look for all those block apis :( and still can't convince managers to drop old versions

Answer (score 0):

Your selector needs to follow the signature:

`- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context`

And to pass it a custom object, that's what the `context` is used for: you set it with `[UIView beginAnimations:someId context:yourCustomObject];`. Note that `yourCustomObject` is not retained !

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pass an arbitrary selector with an arbitrary number of arguments. If you check the documentation, it needs to be of the form

```
(void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
```

Here are the relevant docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/setAnimationDidStopSelector: